# Azure DevOps Pipeline Environment GitVersion name

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

The 'Status' value in Azure DevOps Pipelines Environments is using the initial value of the build number before it is transformed during build using gitversion.yml

My build pipeline YAML starts with:

```
name: $(GITVERSION_MAJOR).$(GITVERSION_MINOR).$(GITVERSION_PATCH).$(Build.BuildId)$(GITVERSION_PRERELEASELABEL)
```

When the build starts Azure DevOps temporarily displays it is:

```
#$(GITVERSION_MAJOR).$(GITVERSION_MINOR).$(GITVERSION_PATCH).64890$(GITVERSION_PRERELEASELABEL)
```

During build, first task that runs is a GitVersion task:

```
    - task: gittools.gitversion.gitversion-task.GitVersion@4
      displayName: GitVersion
      inputs:
        updateAssemblyInfo: true
        preferBundledVersion: false
```

Using following gitversion.yml that is checked into repo:

```
mode: ContinuousDeployment
continuous-delivery-fallback-tag: ''
branches:
  master:
    mode: ContinuousDeployment
    tag: '-dev'
    increment: Minor
    track-merge-target: true
    tracks-release-branches: true
    is-release-branch: false
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: false
  release:
    regex: release?[/]
    mode: ContinuousDeployment
    increment: Minor
    tag: ''
    is-release-branch: true
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: true
  feature:
    regex: feature?[/]
    mode: ContinuousDeployment
    increment: Inherit
    tag: '-alpha'
    is-release-branch: false
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: true
  pull-request:
    mode: ContinuousDeployment
    tag: '-pr'
ignore:
  sha: []
```

After this runs, the build in progress name is automatically updated to:

1.24.0.64890-alpha

However, in the 'Environments' section of Azure DevOps, this change is not picked up and the status remains as:

```
Deployment by $(GITVERSION_MAJOR).$(GITVERSION_MINOR).$(GITVERSION_PATCH).64878$(GITVERSION_PRERELEASELABEL)
```

[image: screenshot of Environments]

I would expect the 'Status' to be set to '1.24.0.64890-alpha' same as what shows in the Pipelines 'Last run' column.

Edit - 2020/06/13

I never found a solution to this, but found an alternative implementation which works in the native Azure DevOps YAML without using GitVersion:

```
# Generate build name - see variables section below
name: '$(Version.MajorMinor).$(Version.Revision)$(Version.Suffix)'

variables:
  Version.MajorMinor: 1.0                                         # Major = non-backward compatible version increment, Minor = backward compatible version increment 
  Version.Revision: $[counter(variables['Version.MajorMinor'],0)] # Increments automatically every build, resets if Version.MajorMinor is changed


  # Set the suffix of the version number depending on whether this is master, pr or other branch
  ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master') }}: 
    Version.Suffix: ''      # master
  ${{ if eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest') }}: 
    Version.Suffix: '-pr'   # pull request
  ${{ if and(ne(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'), ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest')) }}: 
    Version.Suffix: '-pre'  # pre-release
```

The version number generated is then in format:
1.0.0 (master branch)
1.0.0-pr (Pull request)
1.0.0-pre (another other branch)

The revision number is auto incremented every time a build is run.

Comment: Do you mean to the Environment tab? can you attach a screenshot?

Comment: This area is under heavy development and partially in preview state. Submit a bug on Developer Community. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html

Comment: edited to include link to screenshot and have raised as bug over here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/668222/azure-devops-pipeline-environment-gitversion-name.html

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem? I am having the same issue.

Comment: No - but I found an alternative that doesn't require GitVersion - see edited post

Comment: Unfortunately bugs about that are closed on Developer Community even if it is a major issue for everyone :(.